# What is the default idle connection timeout value for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

what is the default idle connection timeout for PostgreSQL, I ran `show idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` query and returned 0, but the value 0 means this option is disabled, but I want to know what is default idle timeout value in seconds or milliseconds when it is disabled

Answer (score 3):

0 means “infinitely long”.

Note that that is not an “idle session timeout”, but a timeout for being idle while a database transaction is open.

A timeout for idle sessions was added in v14 with `idle_session_timeout`.

Comment: Hi All/@Laurenz Albe,

In one of my Postgres 11 servers, idle_in_transaction_session_timeout was set to 0 (that means disabled), but I am seeing  the below error once in every 5 minutes, 
FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout

Since the idle_in_transaction_session_timeout is 0, it doesn't look like the issue is because of this flag idle_in_transaction_session_timeout. Can you please help me to analyze the problem?

Comment: @Suresh Then the parameter is set different from what you think. It could be overridden in the session.